# Convert character to date in R while changing date default format

Tags: r, date, type-conversion, character

I have the following character variable in R:

```
> d <- "06/01/2018"
> class(d)
> "character"
```

I want to convert that to Date, change the default date format, and keep the data type as a Date, so I start with:

```
> d <- as.Date(s, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
> class(d)
> "Date"
```

All is well, however the default date format starts with the year and not the month - I want it to start with the month:

```
> d
> "2018-06-01"
```

So if I format this again, the date starts with the month now, but it turns the variable back to character!

```
> d <- format(d, "%m/%d/%Y")
> d
> "06/01/2018"
> class(d)
> character
```

How can I keep d as Date in this new (non-default) format without being converted back to character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) chron** `print.Date` will always use yyyy-mm-dd but chron will use mm/dd/yy:

```
library(chron)

d <- "06/01/2018"
as.chron(d)
## [1] 06/01/18
```

**2) subclass** You can define an S3 subclass of Date that displays in the desired manner:

```
as.subDate <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("as.subDate")
as.subDate.character <- function(x, ...) {
  structure(as.Date(x, "%m/%d/%Y"), class = c("subDate", "Date"))
}
format.subDate <- function(x, ...) format.Date(x, "%m/%d/%Y")
as.subDate(d)

## [1] "06/01/2018"
```

You might need to add more methods depending on what you want to do.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without installing anything extra from CRAN?

Comment: Have added (2).

Comment: I realize this may not be possible. When you have a `Date` object stored in a variable in R, it appears the default format is to start with the year. Changing that will convert the object to `character`.

Answer (score 0):

By entering just a variable name at the console, it's printed using the default arguments to `print`.  If you want a different format, change how `print` works with a `Date`:

```
Sys.Date()
# [1] "2018-06-04

print.Date <- function (x, max = NULL, ...) {
  if (is.null(max)) 
    max <- getOption("max.print", 9999L)
  n_printed <- min(max, length(x))
  formatted <- strftime(x[seq_len(n_printed)], format = "%m/%d/%Y")
  print(formatted, max = max, ...)
  if (max < length(x)) {
    cat(" [ reached getOption(\"max.print\") -- omitted", 
      length(x) - max, "entries ]\n")
  } else if (length(x) == 0L) {
    cat(class(x)[1L], "of length 0\n")
  }
  invisible(x)
}

Sys.Date()
# [1] "06/04/2018"
```

This is just the standard `print.Date` function with a few edits.

But I do have to comment on this:

> I want to convert that to Date, change the default date format, and keep the data type as a Date

A `Date` vector doesn't have a format. A format can be used when converting it into a `character` vector (which is what `print` does), but a `Date` is really just an `integer` with a different class. The integer gives the number of days past the epoch (1970-01-01):

```
x <- 1
x
# [1] 1
class(x) <- "Date"
x
# [1] "1970-01-02"
```

Comment: But if I use `strftime`, I get back a `character`. I want a `Date`.